# Having issue with array/object looping

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that loops through an object.

I want data on the form

```
group1:Array[1,2,3]

group2:Array[4,5,6]

group2:Array[7,8,9]
```

But instead I get the data on the form

```
group1:Array[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

group2:Array[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

group2:Array[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

That is it copies the values in the first group that I loop through and then add those values to the rest of the groups and I don't want that.
It gets wrong in the function call

`for (var resultGroupElement in value[resultKey].DCTRecord.DCT[resultGroup])`

And I don't know how to fix it. Do you guys perhapse know how to fix it? I have tried to delete the variables without any luck.

Thanks in advance.

```
getData: function(value) {
    var dataArray = [];
    var dataArrayHolder = [];

    for (var resultKey in value) {
        var stopTimeConverted = $.extend(true, {}, convertDateToWorkWithAllBrowsers(value[resultKey].StopTime));
        var resultGroups = value[resultKey].DCTRecord.DCT;
        for (var resultGroup in resultGroups) {
            for (var resultGroupElement in value[resultKey].DCTRecord.DCT[resultGroup]) {//Here is where its going wrong

                if (dataArray[resultGroupElement] != null) {
                    var curResultGroupDCT = dataArray[resultGroupElement];
                }
                else {
                    var curResultGroupDCT = [];
                }

                    curResultGroupDCT.push(
                            [
                                new Date(stopTimeConverted),
                                11
                            ]
                            );
                    dataArray[resultGroupElement] = curResultGroupDCT;
                    delete curResultGroupDCT;
            }
            dataArrayHolder[resultGroup] = dataArray;
            delete dataArray;
        }
    }
    console.log(dataArrayHolder);
}
```

Comment: What the original data looks like?

Comment: You're both using [`delete`](http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/) and [`for in` loops](http://stackoverflow.com/q/500504/1048572) very wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

["delete" deletes a property of the object, not the object.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) dataArray is not actually being deleted, and thus will be appended to for any elements within the next group that have the same name/index/whatever as the ones from the previous group.

Use

```
dataArray = [];
```

and

```
curResultGroupDCT = [];
```

instead.

Comment: Thanks both of you @HamHamJ and @ folkol, it solved my issue =)

Answer (score 0):

[`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) does not do what you think it does.

You keep adding to the same array, replace 'delete dataArray' with 'dataArray = []' to clear it.

```
    dataArrayHolder[resultGroup] = dataArray;
    dataArray = []; //delete dataArray;
}
```